# Can I present My Loginwidow before MAC Login Window

Tags: macos, sfauthorizationpluginview

I am trying to put my own customised  login window before the standard MAC OS X Login window. Acutally , I need to have a stacking / chaining  of window, so that original MAC Login window presented after my customised login window.
I have already tried prelogin agent, but that do not fullfill my requirement , because i want my window to be launched before MAC login window not parallet to MAC Login window.

Thanks for help in advance.

Meet B.

Comment: Just to clarify, this *is* an application you're writing yourself, correct?  (I only ask because this was flagged for migration to [SU](http://superuser.com/), where I think it probably doesn't belong.)

Comment: Yes this would be an application which I will write.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to implement your own authorisation plugin. Here are some references:

- [Authorisation Plug-In Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/Reference/AuthorizationPluginRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001432-CH202-427065)
- [Sample Plugin](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/NullAuthPlugin/Introduction/Intro.html)
- [SFauthorizationPluginView - Authorization plugin with custom GUI](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Reference/SFAuthorizationPluginView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004657-CH3-SW4)
- [Sample Plugin with GUI](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/NameAndPassword/Introduction/Intro.html)

After you plugin is done you need to register it in the policy database using[Authorization Services API](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Reference/authorization_ref/Reference/reference.html) there are guides on how to do this is the links above.
You emphasised the fact that you want you plugin to run before the native OS X plugin, this is all handled by the policy database. The policy database contains a list of authorisation plugins and they are executed in the order they are listed.